# Onclick event open a new page and load an table by doing an api call using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I'm trying to display a table on a new page by calling an API and loading the data in the table. This page is loaded on click of a menuItem.

But the issue I'm facing is that the table is displaying, but not the data I'm intending to. I know that I'm able to fetch the data from the API since i can see that in the console log.

Here is the code:

In this first html file im clickling the menu and calling my next html page i want to load
and also im giving my  id="covidLink" which im calling in my JS FILE.

### pan.html

```
        <div class="navbar">
              <a class="covidText" id="covidLink" href="covidStatusUpdate.html">Covid-19</a>
        </div>
```

In the below js file im making a call to the api and appending the data in tbody.

### Fetchdata.js

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
            
      $("#covidLink").click(function () {
      console.log("Link clicked...");
      requestVirusData();
                   
      });
    });

    function requestVirusData() {             
    $.getJSON('https://api.covid19api.com/summary',
    function(data){
    var countries_list = data.Countries;
    //console.log(countries_list);
      $(countries_list).each(function(i, country_dtls){
      $('#totalbody').append($("<tr>")
      .append($("<td>").append(country_dtls.country))
      .append($("<td>").append(country_dtls.TotalConfirmed))
      .append($("<td>").append(country_dtls.TotalDeaths))
      .append($("<td>").append(country_dtls.TotalRecovered)));
      });
     })
    }
```

### and lastly
statusUpdate.html

```
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm" cellspacing="0" width=80%>
      <thead>
       <tr>
         <th>Country</th>
         <th>TotalConfirmed</th>
         <th>TotalDeaths</th>
         <th>TotalRecovered</th>
       </tr>
      </thead> 
      <tbody id="totalbody">                                                                                                                        
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

What am I supposed to do ? I have to admit that I'm lost here.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you quite understand how AJAX works. You're handling a click on "covidLink". This does **two** things simultaneously.

1. it tells the browser to navigate away from the current page and go to `statusUpdate.html` instead.
2. it runs the `requestVirusData()` function. This gets the data from the API and returns it to the page.

But the problem is: the API call returns the data to the page where the script was called from - i.e. it returns it to `pan.html`. And you've just told the browser to move away from that page. Also, pan.html doesn't contain a table to put the returned data into.

The logical solution here is to link to fetchdata.js from statusUpdate.html instead, and tweak the code slightly so it runs when that page loads, rather than on the click of a button:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  console.log("page loaded...");
  requestVirusData();
});
```

Comment: ADyson thanks for your reply.But i need to call fetchdata.js on click of the "covidLink".

Comment: Now im stuck here as i'm new to Javascript and AJAX and i do not know how to link my javascript function with the statusUpdate.html in this scenario.

Comment: _" i need to call fetchdata.js on click of the "covidLink""_ ....no, you don't. If you still think that then you haven't understood my answer at all. The covidLink link is in the wrong file. Your table is in statusUpdate.html, not pan.html. your covidLink will cause statusupdate.html to load. Once that's loaded, then you can call the API from there and the code will be able to see you table and populate it.

Comment: _" i do not know how to link my javascript function with the statusUpdate.html"_ ...well, how did you link it with pan.html? It will be the same process.

Comment: Thank you ADyson for your reply.

Comment: No problem. So, did it help?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by ADyson i did changes in my code and now im able to display the table with data.
Here are my code changes:

### statusUpdate.html

```
                                           <tbody id="tbody">
                                                    <script>
                                                            var datatable;
                                                            fetch('https://api.covid19api.com/summary')
                                                            .then(function (response) {
                                                                return response.json();
                                                            })
                                                            .then(function (data) {
                                                                appendData(data);
                                                            })
                                                            .catch(function (err) {
                                                                console.log('error: ' + err);
                                                            });

                                                            function appendData(data) {
                                                                var countries_list = data.Countries;
                                                                var tbody = document.getElementById("tbody");

                                                                // clear the table for updating
                                                                $('table tbody').empty();
    
                                                                // hide the table for hidden initialize
                                                                $('table').hide();
    

                                                                // loop over every country
                                                                for (var i in countries_list) {
                                                                    var country_dtls = countries_list[i];
                                                                // replace -1 with unknown
                                                                    for (var o in country_dtls) {
                                                                        if (country_dtls[o] == -1) country_dtls[o] = 'Unknown';
                                                                    }
                                                                    $('table tbody').append(`
                                                                        <tr>
                                                                        <td>${country_dtls.Country}</td>
                                                                        <td>${country_dtls.TotalConfirmed}</td>
                                                                        <td>${country_dtls.TotalDeaths}</td>
                                                                        <td>${country_dtls.TotalRecovered}</td>
                                                                        </tr>`);
                                                            }
                                                            
                                                        }

                                                    // }
                                                    </script>
                                                </tbody>
```

### pan.html

```
<a class="covid" href="statusUpdate.html">Covid-19</a>
```

and now i do not need fetchdata.js obviously.
Hope this helps someone stuck like me :)